# Question on cyclotomic polynomials and the Möbius function

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials, mobius-function

I'm doing an exercise on the Möbius function $\mu$. I've seen this equation but I don't understand it.

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{X}^{n}-1&= \prod_{d \mid n} \phi_d(X) \\
&=\prod_{d \mid n} \left(\mathrm{X}^{\varphi(d)}-\mu(d) \mathrm{X}^{\varphi(d)-1}+\cdots \right) \\
&=\mathrm{X}^{n}-\sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) \mathrm{X}^{\varphi(d)-1} \prod_{q \mid n, q \neq d} \mathrm{X}^{\varphi(q)}+\cdots \\
&=\mathrm{X}^{n}-\sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) \mathrm{X}^{n-1}+\cdots
\end{align*}

I know that $X^{\sum_{d | n } \varphi(d)} = X^n$ but I don't see why we get the term $\sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d) \mathrm{X}^{\varphi(d)-1} \prod_{q \mid n, q \neq d} \mathrm{X}^{\varphi(q)}$.

Comment: That's just expanding the product $\;\prod_{j} \left(x^{n_j}- m_j x^{n_j-1}+\dots\right)=x^{\sum_j n_j}-\sum_j m_j x^{n_j-1}\,\prod_{i \ne j} x^{n_i}+\dots\,$

Comment: I don't see how you got the formula

Comment: You take the $-m_j x^{n_j-1}$ term from one of the parentheses and multiply it by $x^{n_i}$ for all others $i \ne j$, then add those up.